# What is the best format for a ts file for time series analysis?

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I'm just starting with `time series` analysis in `R` and I am having a hard time to figure out the best format of my `ts` file.

I will be importing data into R from a `csv` file and the data frame will look like this:

```
date          sales
2015/01/01    150
2015/02/01    200
2015/03/01    175
...
```

My aim is to break this data into its `time series` components: Seasonal, Trend and Irregular

Can I leave the data ás is'and then convert it into a `ts` format and proceed with my analysis?
I have seen time series data in the following format also:

```
     Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov Dec

2015 150  200  175  ...
2016 250  420  350  ...
...
```

Which of these 2 formats work best for `time series` analysis in `R`? Does it make a difference?

Comment: Define "best", for what type of analysis are you going to use the series? I use the classic that have the package `stats`. I use the function `ts`. For me is better because you must not to have making transformations when you are going to make forecasting for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For monthly data the simplest way is to use `ts()`, e.g.

```
ts(data, start=c(2015,1), freq=12)
```

This will produce the time series object you refer to in your last table. Some functions in R require your time series to be a `ts()`-object such that it can record the frequency often through `tsp()`, e.g. `stats::stl`. `tsp()` returns the properties of the time series, i.e. start date, end date, frequency. Some also require `xts()`-objects from `library(xts)`, often used for hourly or higher frequency data. For multi-seasonal data you can use `msts()` from `library(forecast)` e.g. for `forecast::tbats`.